# What is the right way of setting function globally so its usable in all the controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Currently I have function $timeout in every single controller, and I really want to put it somewhere that I can use it globally everywhere. someone mentioned its best to put it as a service. Is this the correct way of doing this ? if so how can I change the structure of it so it fits in service.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MenuController', MenuController);

    MenuController.$inject = ['navigationService', 'dealService', '$scope', '$timeout', 'ionicMaterialInk', 'ionicMaterialMotion'];
    function MenuController(navigationService, dealService, $scope, $timeout, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion) {
        // Set Header
        $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.showHeader();
        $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.clearFabs();
        $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.setExpanded(false);
        $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.setHeaderFab(false);


        // Delay expansion
        $timeout(function () {

            ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
                selector: '.slide-up'
            });
        }, 300);

        var vm = this;
        vm.menuItems = [];

        navigationService.getAllNavigations()
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                vm.menuItems = data;

                $timeout(function () {
                    // Set Motion
                    ionicMaterialMotion.fadeSlideInRight();

                    // Set Ink
                    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
                }, 100);
            });

        dealService.setCurrentDeal();
    };
})();
```

Currently I have this but its not working !

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .service('globalService', globalService);

    function globalService($http, restServer) {
        var globalService = {
            timeout: timeout()
        };

        return globalService;

        // Delay expansion
        $timeout(function () {

            ionicMaterialMotion.slideUp({
                selector: '.slide-up'
            });
        }, 300);
    };
})();
```

Comment: I'd put it in a JavaScript module that all could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1) Use it as a service
Its possibly not working for you since your service doesn't know what `ionicMaterialMotion` is, you should add a dependency to it.

2) As a function in a global JavaScript file.
Just put a function in some plain JavaScript file, and include it in your `index.html`. Then you can call it from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex; I might be wrong but according to @duffymo there is also an option to put it in module ! in which case there are 3 possible choices ! and so what is the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: Perhaps its a personal preference but I would always rather use a `service` to do that kind of work, its easily injected into every controller you require it. So making your code from above work (just handle proper injection of the ionic) would be my choice.

Comment: everyone is saying that; Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the next:

```
yourApp.controller("generalController", function($scope) {
    // Your code.
});

yourApp.controller("singleController", function($scope, $controller){
     /* Extend generalController*/
     $controller('generalController', {
          $scope: $scope
     });
});
```